# Timeout with HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, timeout, getresponse

I am using HttpWebRequest to read content from website.

```
string url = "http://google.com.vn";
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
request.Timeout = 2000;
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
request.ReadWriteTimeout = 2000;
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

But timeout is not working :(. Can I use backgroundworker to make timeout.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: You are setting timeout for the client, but there is also timeout setting at server, your client side timeout will work in case client side timeout is less the server timeout.

Comment: Also, you are setting a 2s timeout, and you are downloading google home page. That page will definitely download in less than 2s unless you are running on a 56k modem.

Comment: I want if after 2 second, It can't completed download content from url. It will alert "Request time out"

Comment: This works, you are just downloading too fast. To be sure you can create "server" using HttpListener that uses Thread.Sleep(2100); in handleRequest and see it for yourself.